delimiter setting in to_csv pandas
using string of length 3 as seprator in DataFrame.to_csv() pandas
in to_csv() method of DataFrame, I want to set "sep" parameter as '&|$' and tried this code:
 df.to_csv(path_or_buf='Desktop/hello.csv', sep='&|$', lineterminator='&|$')

but I got error:
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

is there any solution to set "delimiter" a 3-character string?

The error message is clear, delimiters are single characters. You would need to write your own splitter function to create a 'normal' set odf csv strings.

You can set an unused character (e. g. some special Unicode character) as delimiter, set path_or_buf to None so that to_csv returns the CSV-data as string, replace the special character in the string by the desired character sequence and store the string as CSV-file.

@MichaelButscher that would work, but then I'd rather make it more explicit, read the lines manually into a series and proceed from there. Also when calling str.split, regex=False needs to be set to prevent the pattern from being treated as regex.

@fsimonjetz I think this isn't necessary. In the CSV output everything is already as it should be except for the delimiters. A simple call to Python's (not pandas') string replace method fixes this without splitting the CSV data into lines.

You should be able to achieve this by converting the DataFrame to a numpy ndarray, and using the np.savetxt function.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 4)), columns=pd.Index(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
)

# Convert to numpy
df_array = df.to_numpy().astype(np.int64)

# Save to csv file
np.savetxt(
    "out.csv",
    df_array,
    fmt="%s",
    delimiter="&|$",
    newline="&|$\n",
    header="&|$".join(list(df.columns.values)),
    comments="",
    encoding="utf-8",
)

Example output with column headers and delimiter at end of line:
A&|$B&|$C&|$D&|$
22&|$51&|$12&|$61&|$
18&|$85&|$73&|$86&|$
8&|$66&|$0&|$42&|$
42&|$87&|$82&|$11&|$
12&|$94&|$11&|$46&|$
4&|$90&|$12&|$31&|$
21&|$66&|$93&|$76&|$
33&|$28&|$12&|$97&|$
10&|$40&|$22&|$82&|$
14&|$30&|$57&|$36&|$

If you do not want your output file to contain header names, simply remove the header parameter from the function.
Hope this helps!
